# PyMongo + Flask: How to render content with jinja?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, pymongo

I use Flask in an application that displays some data from a Mongo database. Scrapy spider writes data. My problem is that the application displays text without a separator. How to keep indents and remove quotes?

For example, a database entry has the following text:
[image]

spider:

```
Reviews = response.css('.listing-review-text::text, .blurred.read-more::text, .response-question::text,' +
                           '.response-answer::text, .listing-review-name::text, .review_name::text').getall()
```

jinja:

```html
{% if card.Reviews %}
   <h3 class="font-weight-normal">Reviews</h3>
   <p>{{card.Reviews}}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% if card.Reviews %}
   <h3 class="font-weight-normal">Reviews</h3>
   {% for review in card.Reviews %}
       <p>{{review}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Iterate over reviews and print them.